# ROS2: name 'Node' is not defined

Tags: ros2, webots

we are working on Webots environment with ROS2. when we launched the following example in the Webots-ros2 tutorial, we got the following error, could you help us to overcome that problem, thanks.

The example link: [Setting up a robot simulation (Advanced)](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Setting-Up-Simulation-Webots-Advanced.html)

**ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/ros2_ws/src$** `ros2 launch my_package robot_launch.py`

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ntukenmez3/.ros/log/2023-09-07-17-39-57-599365-ae-icps-407120-1653965
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
WARNING: No valid Webots directory specified in `ROS2_WEBOTS_HOME` and `WEBOTS_HOME`, fallback to default installation folder /usr/local/webots.
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: name 'Node' is not defined
```

---

**my_robot_driver.py:**

```
import rclpy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

HALF_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_WHEELS = 0.045
WHEEL_RADIUS = 0.025

class MyRobotDriver:
    def init(self, webots_node, properties):
        self.__robot = webots_node.robot

        self.__left_motor = self.__robot.getDevice('left wheel motor')
        self.__right_motor = self.__robot.getDevice('right wheel motor')

        self.__left_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        self.__left_motor.setVelocity(0)

        self.__right_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        self.__right_motor.setVelocity(0)

        self.__target_twist = Twist()

        rclpy.init(args=None)
        self.__node = rclpy.create_node('my_robot_driver')
        self.__node.create_subscription(Twist, 'cmd_vel', self.__cmd_vel_callback, 1)

    def __cmd_vel_callback(self, twist):
        self.__target_twist = twist

    def step(self):
        rclpy.spin_once(self.__node, timeout_sec=0)

        forward_speed = self.__target_twist.linear.x
        angular_speed = self.__target_twist.angular.z

        command_motor_left = (forward_speed - angular_speed * HALF_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_WHEELS) / WHEEL_RADIUS
        command_motor_right = (forward_speed + angular_speed * HALF_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_WHEELS) / WHEEL_RADIUS

        self.__left_motor.setVelocity(command_motor_left)
        self.__right_motor.setVelocity(command_motor_right)
```

**obstacle_avoider.py:**

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import Range
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist


MAX_RANGE = 0.15


class ObstacleAvoider(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('obstacle_avoider')

        self.__publisher = self.create_publisher(Twist, 'cmd_vel', 1)

        self.create_subscription(Range, 'left_sensor', self.__left_sensor_callback, 1)
        self.create_subscription(Range, 'right_sensor', self.__right_sensor_callback, 1)

    def __left_sensor_callback(self, message):
        self.__left_sensor_value = message.range

    def __right_sensor_callback(self, message):
        self.__right_sensor_value = message.range

        command_message = Twist()

        command_message.linear.x = 0.1

        if self.__left_sensor_value < 0.9 * MAX_RANGE or self.__right_sensor_value < 0.9 * MAX_RANGE:
            command_message.angular.z = -2.0

        self.__publisher.publish(command_message)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    avoider = ObstacleAvoider()
    rclpy.spin(avoider)
    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    avoider.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**my_robot.urdf:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="My robot">
    <webots>
        <device reference="ds0" type="DistanceSensor">
            <ros>
                <topicName>/left_sensor</topicName>
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            </ros>
        </device>
        <device reference="ds1" type="DistanceSensor">
            <ros>
                <topicName>/right_sensor</topicName>
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            </ros>
        </device>
        <plugin type="my_package.my_robot_driver.MyRobotDriver" />
    </webots>
</robot>
```

**robot_launch.py:**

```
import os
import launch
from launch import LaunchDescription
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from webots_ros2_driver.webots_launcher import WebotsLauncher
from webots_ros2_driver.webots_controller import WebotsController


def generate_launch_description():
    package_dir = get_package_share_directory('my_package')
    robot_description_path = os.path.join(package_dir, 'resource', 'my_robot.urdf')

    webots = WebotsLauncher(
        world=os.path.join(package_dir, 'worlds', 'my_world.wbt')
    )

    my_robot_driver = WebotsController(
        robot_name='my_robot',
        parameters=[
            {'robot_description': robot_description_path},
        ]
    )

    obstacle_avoider = Node(
        package='my_package',
        executable='obstacle_avoider',
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        webots,
        my_robot_driver,
        obstacle_avoider,
        launch.actions.RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=launch.event_handlers.OnProcessExit(
                target_action=webots,
                on_exit=[launch.actions.EmitEvent(event=launch.events.Shutdown())],
            )
        )
    ])
```

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'my_package'
data_files = []
data_files.append(('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages', ['resource/' + package_name]))
data_files.append(('share/' + package_name + '/launch', ['launch/robot_launch.py']))
data_files.append(('share/' + package_name + '/worlds', ['worlds/my_world.wbt']))
data_files.append(('share/' + package_name + '/resource', ['resource/my_robot.urdf']))
data_files.append(('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']))
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=data_files,
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='user',
    maintainer_email='user.name@mail.com',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_robot_driver = my_package.my_robot_driver:main',
            'obstacle_avoider = my_package.obstacle_avoider:main'
    ],
    },
)
```

Comment: did you try to import Node in launch file. from launch_ros.actions import Node

Comment: I will try now, thanks.

Comment: I really appreciate for that. It works now. How did you figure out this problem before, I mean How did you realize this is the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot

```
from launch_ros.actions import Node
```

in your *robot_launch.py* file